# Unable to exclude URL's in the servlet mapping in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller in Spring MVC 3.2 which I want to allow the follow url's:
http://localhost:8080/mypage
http://localhost:8080/mypage/
http://localhost:8080/mypage/foo

I want to exclude anything else i.e. http://localhost:8080/mypage/bar should result in an error. Currently bar gets mapped to the getStuff method.

I assume I must be able to accomplish this without using a filter?

My servlet mapping looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mypage/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The controller request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getView(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("myform") final MyForm form)  {
        return "myview";
}
@ResponseBody
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
@RequestMapping(value = "/save")
public String onSave(@RequestBody MyForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
        return "saved";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `Spring MVC` filters called `Interceptors`.

If you write your own `Interceptor` you have two options as below:

**1. option:**

Use the `postHandle()` method to check your conditions. If you use the `postHandle()` method you have access to the `ModelAndView` and if your url doesn't match with one of your 3 url's you just can throw an `Exception` or change the `ModelAndView`.

**2. option:**

Use the `preHandle()` method, check the url's and if they don't match throw a `ModelAndViewDefiningException` with a `new ModelAndView()` like this: 
`ModelAndViewDefiningException(new ModelAndView("errorPage"))`

Answer (score 0):

The `<url-pattern>` Tag of servlet does not support exclusions. This is a limitation of the Servlet specification.
You have to create this functionality programmatically in a `filter`.